# Lenovo 75Hz monitor not working with 2010 Macbook via mini-DP to HDMI

Tags: display, hdmi, macbook, external-display, displayport

I just bought the [Lenovo C24-25](https://www.lenovo.com/gb/en/accessories-and-monitors/monitors/home/C24-25A20238FD023-8inch-Monitor-HDMI/p/66B0KAC1UK) monitor for my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010). I'm using [this cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0134V3KIA/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which I've used on a different (Windows) laptop successfully. When I connect the laptop to the monitor, the laptop screen goes black briefly but then goes back to normal. In System Preferences > Display, no monitor shows up and clicking Detect Displays does nothing.

I've heard people have had problems with 75Hz not working on Macs, but since it's not detecting the display in any way, there's no way for me to change it to 60Hz. Furthermore, the monitor does not leave standby mode when connected to the Macbook, even if I press some keys etc. and so I cannot access the menu.

I've tried connecting the monitor to my Windows laptop via a HDMI-HDMI cable and it works. I tried connecting the Macbook to my TV via the miniDP-HDMI cable and the TV just stayed black despite selecting the correct HDMI output.

I'm really not sure what to do here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I tried it with an iMac via miniDP-HDMI and it works. Defaults to 60Hz.

EDIT2: Should I try ordering a USB-HDMI cable?

Comment: The cable is not bi-directional.  Are you connecting the HDMI to the display or the Macbook?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: The MBP has only Mini-DP [& the display is HDMI or VGA], so it has to be the right way round. Test it from cold boot [ie plug it in before booting]. DisplayPort is only theoretically hot-pluggable. Many times, it doesn't work. A 2010 is likely to be more flaky at hot-plugging than a modern machine.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've tried that but I can try again. I've just added an edit to my post that I got it to work with the same cable on my iMac.

Comment: I'm tempted to think there's something wrong with the MBP's DP port, but idk how to diagnose. USB-HDMI isn't much use to you on a USB2 port.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's what I'm thinking as well, I'll probably take it to a tech repair shop.

Comment: @JP - You can also try purchasing an active DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.  The one you purchased is passive, and some of the reviews (Mac owners), indicate that was a problem.  I have never had much luck with Amazon Basic products unless they were say just simply USB cables.

Comment: @Ramhound What's the difference? I bought this one because it worked for me before (on Windows though). And the cable I bought worked with my iMac and monitor.

Comment: The difference between an active and passive cable is well documented.  I thought you were seeking suggestions to solve the problem?  *Having experienced purchasing adapters that didn't work, then going out, and purchasing an adapter from a different brand and it working I was just sharing my knowledge.*